# sendtestemail Failing on GCE docker-compose

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, django, docker-compose

I'm setting up Weblate on Google Cloud Platform (GCE using Container-Optimized OS) and deploying via Docker Compose using the HTTPS configuration.

I've followed these tutorials:

- [Weblate: Installing using Docker](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/install/docker.html#quick-docker)
- [Google: Running Docker Compose with Docker](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-compose-on-container-optimized-os)

Weblate is running fine, however, emails aren't sending due to the following:

```
ERROR Handled exception: OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/weblate", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Weblate==3.8', 'console_scripts', 'weblate')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/weblate/runner.py", line 34, in main
    execute_from_command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/sendtestemail.py", line 33, in handle
    recipient_list=kwargs['email'],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 63, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I've tried is playing with various settings in the `docker-compose-https.override.yml` file, namely omitting certain settings to auto configure and changing the email address specified, specifying the port for mail, and changing SSL/TLS settings.

Here are the relevant parts of the configuration:

```yml
…
WEBLATE_EMAIL_HOST: "smtp-relay.gmail.com"
WEBLATE_SERVER_EMAIL: "weblate@example.org"
WEBLATE_DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL: "weblate@example.org"
WEBLATE_USE_SSL: 0
WEBLATE_USE_TLS: 1
WEBLATE_ALLOWED_HOSTS: "i18n.example.org"
…
```

I'm unsure what the problem is or where to look to address it. Could anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't specify the port. The correct configuration for my setup is:

```yml
…
WEBLATE_EMAIL_HOST: "smtp-relay.gmail.com"
WEBLATE_EMAIL_PORT: 587
WEBLATE_SERVER_EMAIL: "weblate@example.org"
WEBLATE_DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL: "weblate@example.org"
WEBLATE_USE_SSL: 0
WEBLATE_USE_TLS: 1
WEBLATE_ALLOWED_HOSTS: "i18n.example.org"
```